# Converting Decimal To Integer

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string retval;

retval = Decimal.ToInt32(1899.99M).ToString();
```

the output is 1899. But i want to if decimal is bigger  .5 then output is 1900 else then ouput is 1899. how can i do this? thanks in advance !

Comment: Which rounding do you want at exactly `.5`? Banker's round or towards infinity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Math.Round first.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx

Answer (score 3):

When using [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274.aspx) You have two choices for rounding `x.5`:

Banker's round / Round to even. Avoids biases, by sometimes rounding up(1.5=>2) and sometimes rounding down(0.5=>0), used by default if you don't specify the parameter.

```
Int32 i=Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

The rounding you learn at school, where it always rounds towards infinity (0.5=>1, -0.5=>-1)

```
Int32 i=Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
Double d = 1899.99;
Int32 i = Math.Round(d);
String retval = i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Decimal.ToInt32(Math.Round(1899.99M)).ToString();
```